# H18 error, sock=backen. Connection interrupted half-way through response

Tags: json, flask, heroku, gunicorn, interrupt

I have a small Flask application up on Heroku which serves json data to be displayed on a `canvas` tag controlled by some Chart.js script. Everything works fine when testing with `heroku local web` but when pushing to Heroku and visiting the page online, I intermittently get the **H18 error** stating that the server has closed the connection before the response finished loading. Some details:

- The data I am sending is somewhat large (I don't have the experience to judge if *very* large) but the json file I am serving would be 674 KB
- When the response does load properly, say, 1 in 5 times; it takes between 700 ms to 1.5 s. When it fails, it can do so in the first 50 ms or much later, so it *feels* like a connection issue, and would be unrelated to timeout, right?
- I am running gunicorn 20.0.4 and have tried 20.0.3 to no avail (just a shot in the dark)
- I am testing all of this in a single free dyno. I wonder if that has anything to do with the issue.

Looking forward to hearing any suggestions on how to tackle this. Cheers everyone!